# What kind of conjugation is used here? 「取らじ」

Tags: conjugations

Just encountered in some Japanese text. I understand it's conjugated in the base negative form of the verb but I'm baffled as to what the じ means.

Comment: It would help if you could post the context in which 取らじ appeared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a Classical Japanese particle, nowadays only used as frequent as "methinks".

It means exactly what *must not* (as in 'I suppose the pie must not be ready yet') does in English, and attaches to Classical 未然形 of a verb or adjective (that is, the form which the negative -ず and -ぬ appends to).

See: [the entry of じ](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/92527/m1u/%E3%81%98/) in a Japanese-Japanese dictionary